# in TamperMonkey script, is there anyway to force a lazy load page to completely load?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, tampermonkey

I want to re-format a web page; but its lazy loading is problematic.  
This is flexbox list of transactions, with a few 16X16 icons.
So, its not a lazy-loading of images.  
i.e. the page loads as you scroll.

(...time to show how dumb I am...)  
Is there a way to force the page to completely,... wait for DOM idle,... and then get on with re-formatting the page?

[in the past, I have seen pages that if you jump to the bottom of a page, it leaves the middle of page unloaded]  
I do not know if that is even a possibly with this site; and my current test page is too small to test for it.  But would like to avoid the possibly of it happening in the future (as the site content grows).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure how else to phase it.
I want to get the entire HTML page read into my browser buffer; before continuing on with my web page formatting.
My formatting script will heavily modifying the DOM.

So with lazy loading; I would need to detect anytime there was a DOM mutation and do more reformatting.

Of coarse, the much bigger problem is since my script is doing fairly large changes to the DOM; the trick will be to find the new loaded part [via the lazy load] and reformat just DOM branches and re-integrate them into my munged DOM branches.

if everything is loaded, its just cake